# Typehint a property to a more specific class than the interface returned by the function used to initialize it

Tags: php, type-hinting, phpstan

I’m trying to up my phpstan setup to level 3, but I’m getting an error like this:

```
Property Something::$repository (SpecificRepository) does not accept RepositoryInterface.
```

On a class that looks like this:

```
class Something
{
    /** @var SpecificRepository */
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(ORM $orm)
    {
        $this->orm = $orm;
        $this->repository = $orm->getRepository(Something::class);
    }
}
```

I understand that my ORM’s `getRepository` method returns `RepositoryInterface` because it can’t be more specific, but I need the `@var` typehint in order to tell my IDE tools and phpstan that in this class, `$repository` is more specifically a `SpecificRepository`. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Just realized I can also simply `@phpstan-ignore-next-line`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPStan isn't going to run your code or look at your arguments to understand that this method is going to return a specific type of object -- it's just going to look at the method's return signature. Thus, from PHPStan's point of view, it's not guaranteed that `getRepository()` will return an instance of `SpecificRepository`, which means that it's not guaranteed that `$this->repository` will contain an instance of `SpecificRepository`. However, you've attempted to tell PHPStan just that via your `@var` typehint -- and PHPStan is (correctly) telling you that you're mistaken. To get the benefit of IDE autocompletion on a more specific class, you could typehint the attribute to its generic interface and then write a getter class that verifies the more specific class you're expecting:

```
protected RepositoryInterface $repository;

protected function getSpecificRepository(): SpecificRepository
{
    if ($this->repository instanceof SpecificRepository === false) {
        throw new Exception('Expected an instance of SpecificRepository');
    }
    return $this->repository;
}
```

Then use `$this->getSpecificRepository()` in your code instead of `$this->repository`.

Comment: PHPStan can be made to understand such code with extensions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71117665/565782

Comment: Oh ok, so either I "protect" the class uncertainty with an exception, either I write a custom PHPStan extension. Thanks!

Comment: Accepting this answer as this is probably "the" way, even though I admit I don’t like it! It probably comes from me doing way more functional programming without exceptions than OOP these days :)

Answer (score 1):

PHPStan can understand that `$em->getRepository(Something::class);` returns SpecificRepository if you comply with two conditions:

1. You install the phpstan-doctrine extension
2. Something is an entity class and it has `repositoryClass` set in its entity metadata.

Comment: Oh okay, but since I’m using CycleORM instead of Doctrine, I guess that wouldn’t work. I could have a look at that extension though!